# Doorkeeper - Reject access token request if user not an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Using password-grant OAuth-2 flow, If a non-admin user requests an access token with `scope: 'admin'` I want to be able to reject that from happening - I'm using doorkeeper with devise.

Currently any old user can ask for any scope and by default it gets granted.

I don't see an obvious hook in doorkeeper to perform this sort of logic. Where/how should I configure this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible with doorkeeper 3.x.  You'd need to monkeypatch the `OAuth::PreAuthorization` class or fork the gem to add the required logic.

I had a similar need, so I made this into a config option where you can specify your own `preauth` class.  The code is [here](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/compare/master...redterror:feature/alt_preauth).  The doorkeeper maintainers indicated [they wanted to think more about the feature](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/issues/667).

Answer (score 0):

Using Doorkeeper 4.x.x I am checking the presence of an 'admin' scope and if the current user is admin in the Doorkeeper's initializer:

```
resource_owner_from_credentials do
  user = User.find_for_database_authentication(login: params[:login])
  if user&.active_for_authentication? && 
    user.valid_for_authentication? { user.valid_password? params[:password] }
      admin_scope = params[:scope]&.split&.include?('admin')
      user if admin_scope && user.admin? || !admin_scope
    end
  end
end
```